# MySQL Command to Remove Special Characters

Tags: mysql

what is the mysql command to remove all occurrences of some character like â€ in particular column of tableA in databaseA . this column is a text area column whose each row contains a paragraph of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REPLACE` should work.

Take a good look at what you [can do with strings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html).

Example:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET column = REPLACE( colummn, 'â€', 'replacement string' );
```

This should do the job.

Good luck!